# Replace element in a String java

Tags: java, android, string

I am trying to remove some special char from my string and replace it with other string, i write this method but it not work fine :

```
 private String nameNormalizer(String nameString) {

        char[] LETTERS_TO_REPLACE = new char[]{
                'À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Æ',
                'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', '&',
                'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï',
                'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Ö', 'Œ',
                'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü',
                'Ç', 'Č',
                'Ñ',
                'Š', 'ß',
                'Ž'
        };

        String[] LETTERS_REPLACEMENT = new String[]{ //
                "A", "A", "A", "A", "AE", "AE",
                "E", "E", "E", "E", "E",
                "I", "I", "I", "I",
                "O", "O", "O", "OE", "OE",
                "U", "U", "U", "UE",
                "C", "C",
                "N",
                "S", "SS",
                "Z"
        };

        char[] surnameArray = nameString.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
        int i_s = 0;
        int k =0;
        int len_s = LETTERS_TO_REPLACE.length;
        int len_name = nameString.length();
        StringBuilder sb_s = new StringBuilder();


        while(k < len_name) {

            String b_s = ;

            while (i_s < len_s){

                if((surnameArray[k] == LETTERS_TO_REPLACE[i_s])) {

                    b_s =(LETTERS_REPLACEMENT[i_s]);
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    b_s = "" + surnameArray[k];
                    i_s++;
                }
            }
            sb_s.append(b_s);
            k++;
        }

        String newName = sb_s.toString();

        return newName;

    }
```

My method replace only the first occurence and after append the original char element on newName ...

How i can match all char on string and edit it?

Comment: I'd be curious why you're doing this.  Those aren't special characters-  they're letters.  In some languages the users will not understand the words without those marks, and comparing words without those marks can give invalid results.  This is generally not a good idea, unless you have a very special reason.

Comment: Although if you are going to do this-  holding a map of old letter->replacement is a better idea than 2 independent arrays-  less chance of going out of sync, and you can check if a letter should be replaced just by a .contains() check.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i do this because i need to generate a code with this rule... hasmap is a good idea maybe, but i think that it not resolve my problem because the lenght of two array now is the same...

Comment: No, you probably don't want to generate a code with this rule-  it almost certainly will provide a horrible experience for your users.  These are not replacements for one another linguistically and will not be understood by most native speakers.

Comment: These are a code rules of my country. The code is unique and valid only in my country, but the people can set the "special caracter" for generate it

Comment: `b_s = "" + surnameArray[k];` b_s is not initialized correctly, and you keep only the last letter. Move the "" to the declaration and do `b_s = b_s + surname...` !?

Comment: i do `b_s = "" + surnameArray[k]` because ` surnameArray[k]` is a char, i don't need to add it to b_s, but i use it for append string on stringbuilder

Comment: I resolve with an hasmap thanks for all reply